# Is there a good site for tracking your ranking on Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a good site for tracking what your app's ranking is per category on Android market. A long time ago androidstats.com seemed to work, but its long history.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect site for you brand new http://androidapptracker.com - lets you save apps to your profile and track them in each category etc also has a pro tracker coming out soon with hourly updates

Comment: It has migrated to http://rankednow.com/. I did not try it yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Cyrket](http://www.cyrket.com/m/android/) looks as if it may have what you are looking for. Simply click a category and change the sorting type. I have never seen androidstats.com, so I can't tell you if it compares, though.

Comment: This link is not working anymore.

Answer (score -2):

[AndroidRanking](http://www.androidranking.com) is another good choice. It shows you the ranking of your app in different countries, and plot graphs for you to see the ranking movements.

Comment: Site looks to be a flash portal now.